# Quick Action Visibility that references User checkbox doesn't work - appears to obey FLS?

Tags: administration, field-level-security, visibility, app-builder, dynamic-actions

Video demonstration: https://www.screencast.com/t/k55kD1BE4

Can a field that is hidden via FLS not be used to dynamically display a quick action under visibility on a custom object via App Builder using Dynamic Actions?

- User.EL_Manager__c (FLS hidden to all but admins) - Does **not** work and the action is never diplayed despite being checked on the User record
- *Object__c*.User_is_EL_Manager__c (open to all profiles) **Does** work and the action is conditionally displayed if it is checked on the User record

If FLS for User fields does in fact determine whether or not Dynamic Actions are displayed for end users, is that documented somewhere? Or is this a bug?

Comment: The only other thought on this that I had would be to make the field "Visible" for the end user's profile, but check "Edit Access" for the field on the profile... although that's not how our org is setup, it's an option I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying Lightning APIs always honor field level security, and the conditions are checked locally on the client, rather than the server, as it was in the Classic UI. The net result is that the user must be able to view the field in order to have the conditions be checked properly.